# How to utilize a user-defined url action in asp,net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

My hope is to provide a method to end users that will let them enter a value 'SmallBuildingCompany', and then use this value to make a custom url that will redirect to an informational view.  so for example, www.app.com/SmallBuildingCompany.  Can anyone point me to some information to help on this?

edited 161024
My attempt so far:

I added this within RouteConfig.

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "Organization",
        "O/{uniqueCompanyName}",
        new { controller = "Organization", action = "Info" }
```

and added a new controller method and view under the organization controller.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Info(string uniqueCompanyName)
{
    var Org = db.Organizations.Where(u => u.uniqueCompanyName == uniqueCompanyName).FirstOrDefault();

    Organization organization = await db.Organizations.FindAsync(Org.OrgId);

    return View("Info");
}
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `SmallBuildingCompany` part of the URL as a parameter for an action that is used to display every informational view.

Set up the Route in Global.asax.cs to extract the company name as parameter and pass it to the Index action of CompanyInfoController:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
   // Sample URL: /SmallBuildingCompany
   RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "CompanyInfo",
        "{uniqueCompanyName}",
        new { controller = "CompanyInfo", action = "Index" }
   );
}
```

Note that this Route will probably break the default route (`{controller}/{action}/{id}`), so maybe you want to prefix your "Info" route:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
       // Sample URL: Info/SmallBuildingCompany
       RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "CompanyInfo",
            "Info/{uniqueCompanyName}",
            new { controller = "CompanyInfo", action = "Index" }
       );
    }
```

Then the CompanyInfoController Index action can use the `uniqueCompanyName` parameter to retrieve the infos from the database.

```
public ActionResult Index(string uniqueCompanyName) {
    var company = dbContext.Companies.Single(c => c.UniqueName == uniqueCompanyName);
    var infoViewModel = new CompanyInfoViewModel {  
        UniqueName = company.UniqueName  
    }
    return View("Index", infoViewModel);
}
```

[ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#adding_routes_to_an_mvc_application)

Comment: I added what I thought might work, but the page is displaying as not found.  My goal is to give an anonymous user access to this essential organization home page.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can use http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger to check which routes will be hit.